# Oracle package invalidated automatically

Tags: oracle, session, package

We have a oracle 12.1 Prod database. One of the packages in the database become invalid abruptly and all the sessions have the state of that package has been invalidated. We are sure that there was no manual actions (Deployment, DDL, Compile etc.. ) performed on the database. Is there any other way that package can become invalid automatically?

This package is directly referencing 3 remote database tables using DB link.

Comment: Oracle may invalidate objects automatically for its own internal purposes. It doesn't necessarily mean that the package won't work, only that it must be recompiled - probably to resolve a dependency (like reopening a closed DB link) - before it can run again. This recompilation should happen automatically at runtime, if not sooner. Are you getting a specific error when trying to execute this package?

Comment: Is the package actually invalid - or is it only that the state has been invalidated? You mentioned both, but [they mean different things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74796020/266304).

Comment: Hi pmdba, We got this error ORA-04068 and  ORA-04061. The error disappeared after restarting the sessions. In which scenario the Oracle will recompile the package?

Comment: Alex Poole,  the package was recompiled automatically( not sure why - we are sure that no manual action done) and the sessions having the package state is invalidated. May i know is there any possibility to recompile package automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If any dependency undergoes a DDL operation, it will invalidate stored PL/SQL programs that depend on it. It could be a table, a synonym, a view, another PL/SQL routine, etc.. I suggest you look at dba_dependencies to see what the dependencies are for your package, then look at dba_objects for every one of those objects to see what has a recent last_ddl_time value. Don't forget the remote objects on the other side of that database link. When you find it, you are well on your way to finding the root cause. If you can't figure out what DDL is hitting that object, enable DDL auditing so you can capture the event the next time it happens.

If you find that the offending object cannot avoid undergoing DDL for some reason, then you may need to consider breaking the dependency on it by embedding your reference to it inside an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your response. We checked dba_dependencies and last_ddl_time, timestamp of referenced objects. Nothing is changed. But the last_ddl_time, timestamp of the invalid package reflects the time of the invalid error.

Comment: I suggest adding DDL auditing, either through a DDL trigger or via the parameter enabled_ddl_logging=true (writes to the alert log), on both databases involved. The next time this happens, look for something that happened at that time. Make sure you're own PL/SQL routine isn't doing any DDL either (like creating or dropping a work table) unless you reference it exclusively with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.